# Customizing sign in commons page for Microsoft Azure (using react-adal)

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I have a react application I am using with Azure Active Directory to allow my users to log into my company's web services. I have a pretty basic setup that works well and allows the user to log in and navigate around our enterprise application. The problem that I am currently facing involves the login screen that I am redirected to using this plugin (screenshot below). I need to change the background to my company's logo, and I have no idea how to do it.

[image]

It looks like I am being taken to a common page so that the user can enter their credentials first before azure decides if they should be allowed to enter the application. I am confused on how to customize this template, and am at a loss on where to look as I am not quite sure if the configuration would be a part of the individual tenant or a corporate branding configuration. Any direction/advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure AD does provide a feature to customize or brand a few elements for the sign-in pages.

**NOTE**: This feature isn't available for Free version. You may need at least a Basic or higher version like Premium P1, P2 or O365 license.

You can read more about versions and feature comparisons here - [Azure Active Directory Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/)

[image]
[image]

**How to Customize your Azure AD sign-in page**

Microsoft Docs - [Add branding to your organization's Azure Active Directory sign-in page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/customize-branding)

In Azure Portal navigate to "Azure Active Directory" > "Company branding" (in Manage section)

[image]

Few of the elements that can be branded are:

- Sign-in page background image (I guess this is the one you're looking for)
- Banner logo
- Text shown at the bottom of Sign-in page.
- Background color
- Square logo image.